# Soldering 19-Pin HDMI Female Connector

Tags: soldering, hdmi

I am looking to solder this 19 pin hdmi cable with small wires (possible a single wire) to convert it to another connector.

[image: HDMI Female Connector]

I expected the connector to be a have bigger spacing between the pins. How do I proceed with soldering this? If I can get a PCB Board, how would I actually solder this without touching one another?

I have never done soldering this tiny before. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For hand-soldering onto a PCB - Lots of flux, teeny tiny bit of solder.

Comment: You might want a breakout board

Comment: The other alternative would be to get a pre-made cable with a socket, cut it and fan out the wires. They're still tiny but you can splice them seperately.

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens of inexpensive "breakout board" products available for HDMI connector. You are correct that attempting to solder to that connector will be extremely difficult, especially without any kind of PC board (which it was designed for).

[image: Example HDMI breakout board]

[image: Another example]

[image: And another]

Comment: Thank you. I just don't want to wait another 2 weeks for shipping of the item. I can't get it locally so I have to get it via eBay. I will try making a PCB as @MethieuL but just order one of these as a backup plan ;)

Comment: Remember that the PC board also provides the PHYSICAL attachment. The connector on its own provides NO means of physical mounting to anything.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solder this is to made a PCB. This connector mount on the PCB, so if you make the correct footprint, the connector will "snap" into the PCB and all the little pins will be on their correct tracks. Most PCB mask feel "anti-soldering", so it is quite easy to not solder 2 pin together if you go easy on the tin. You can use Flux also, but some manufacturer already place flux on the pin of the PCB and some tin come already mix with some flux in it. You start by soldering the 4 big pins first so the connector don't move and after you can go 1 pin at the time.

With these tracks you can lead them to most conventionnal and easier part to solder with wire or what ever.

If you don't use a PCB, well it is more about dexterity and patience than any special technique

Finaly, go slowly if you don't have a microscope, it could a real pain to see if you short 2 pins together.

Comment: I will try to make a PCB and just connect the 4 pins on the hdmi without solder and see if it turns out good ;)